# Connection getting closed when the connection is idle for more than 5 minutes in oracle jdbc thin connection

Tags: java, database, oracle, jdbc, database-connection

This code snippet executes a query then program sleeps for 5 minutes and after it returns false for isValid method.
uses jdbc thin client.
max_idle_time is set to 0 on db .
For local machine DB Instance, connection is not getting closed. So I am guessing, it must be related to my network. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
package com.oracle.jdbc.test;
import java.sql.*;  
public class JDBCTest {

    public static void main(String args[]){  
    try{  
    //step1 load the driver class  
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  

    //step2 create  the connection object  
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@****","****","****");  

    //step3 create the statement object  
    Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  

    //step4 execute query  
    ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select 1 from dual");  
    while(rs.next())  
    System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));  

    //step5 close the connection object  
    Thread.sleep(300000);
    System.out.println(con.isValid(1));
    stmt.executeQuery("select 1 from dual");

    }catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}  

    }  
}

enter code here
```

Comment: Normally, the issue is a firewall between your machine and the database that needs to be configured to allow persistent connections.

Comment: Most firewalls do not timeout connections unless they are specific application-level firewalls like Oracle's AVDF appliance; they either accept or reject them outright. If the initial connection is going through and then is timed out and you're most likely not using an application firewall, then it is probably a server-side user profile in the database that is limiting things. Have the DBA check your database user profile to make sure. You should also check your application logs to see if they are returning any other errors.

Comment: A fine example of the typical, it's the network, no it's the database conversation.

Comment: @pmdba the thing is both are hosted in OCI. I tested one ADW instance as well as a DB installed in Compute Instance. Maybe it has something to do with OCI network parameters.

Comment: @pmdba did you mean the idle_time and other parameters in the user profile that I am using?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Not to say it couldn't also be a network issue, but if the disconnect/timeout is that predictable I'd look at the database first.

Comment: Try to run this query `select * from user_resource_limits` .Anything from exception stack trace ?

Comment: @Kumar All parameters are unlimited. and no exceptions. Do u want to see v$Session table?

Comment: You can try to turn on "keepalive" by setting "ENABLE=BROKEN" in the JDBC url. Liks this: "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ENABLE=BROKEN)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=<hostname>)(PORT=<port>))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=<servicename>)))"

Comment: did you figure it out, I am encountering the exact same issue

Comment: @yolob21 it was a network issue related to OCI autonomous database.  I don't know how it got solved, but suddenly one day it began to work.

Comment: @yolob21 make sure that you have direct connection from your ADB to your application. Not through internet or through a proxy VPN. create a network rule to allow access to your IP